# Android ActivityNotFoundException despite everything being correct in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created this simplest possible service project (based on [this](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html)) in Eclipse 3.8 with the most up to date Android Tools and posted it here:
https://github.com/8enmann/hello-service/

I get the following error when I start it:

```
02-03 00:18:45.984: E/AndroidRuntime(20145): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.softmann/net.softmann.HelloActivity}:
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {net.softmann/net.softmann.HelloService}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

But it is in my manifest!! What am I doing wrong? I have also tried using "net.softmann.HelloService" instead of ".HelloService" and still no luck.

Comment: add activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: HelloService extends Service?. post the manifest and the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says you're trying to start an *activity* `net.softmann/net.softmann.HelloService` and it is not found.

Looking at your manifest file, you have a *service*  with such name.

Looking at your activity code, you have

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HelloService.class));
```

Start services with `startService()` and not `startActivity()`.